# How to simplify an error callback in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, error-handling

I have a parent component that handles an error callback from its child components however in keeping with do not repeat yourself there seems to be a lot of repitition in my code id like to eliminate.

```
    function BasicInfo() {
    const {shell, ageAndGender, body} = styles;
    const {dispatch, state: {firstname}} = useSignUpState();
    const [firstnameError, setFirstnameError] = useState(true);
    const [ageError, setAgeError] = useState(true);
    const [genderError, setGenderError] = useState(true);
    const [sexualOrientationError, setSexualOrientationError] = useState(true);
    const [heightError, setHeightError] = useState(true);

    const setUserAgeError = useCallback(val => {
        setAgeError(val);
    }, [setAgeError]);

    const setUserGenderError = useCallback(val => {
        setGenderError(val);
    }, [setGenderError]);

    const setUserSexualOrientationError = useCallback(val => {
        setSexualOrientationError(val);
    }, [setSexualOrientationError]);

    const setUserHeightError = useCallback(val => {
        setHeightError(val);
    }, [setHeightError]);

    const handleError = () => {
        return firstnameError || ageError || sexualOrientationError || genderError || heightError;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (firstname === '') {
            setFirstnameError(true);
        } else setFirstnameError(false);
    }, [firstname])

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
            <View style={shell}>
                <View style={{flex: 10}}>
                    <SignUpHeader title={`Enter a bit about\nyourself`} page={1}/>
                    <View style={body}>
                        <TextInput
                            autoComplete
                            mode="outlined"
                            label="Firstname"
                            value={firstname}
                            onChangeText={firstname => dispatch(setFirstname(firstname))}
                            style={{maxHeight: 64, marginBottom: 32}}
                            activeOutlineColor={"#000"}
                            outlineColor={"#DBDBDB"}
                            theme={{
                                colors: {
                                    text: "#000",
                                    placeholder: "#878787",
                                    background: "#FFF"
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                        <View style={ageAndGender}>
                            <AgeButton setBasicInfoError={setUserAgeError}/>
                            <GenderButton setBasicInfoError={setUserGenderError}/>
                        </View>
                        <SexualOrientationButton setBasicInfoError={setUserSexualOrientationError}/>
                        <HeightButton setBasicInfoError={setUserHeightError}/>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <SignUpFooter
                    buttonTitle="Next"
                    disabled={handleError()}
                    route="BasicInfo"
                    title={`Basic\nInfo`}
                />
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}
```

As you can see in the code above every error is passed down to its child, does something very similar to my `firstname` `useEffect` which checks if its not valid and sets a boolean which is then checked by the parent.
Is there a way to maybe create just one callback as say an array and say if length is > 1 set the error? Any help with this would be great to avoid duplication! Thanks

Comment: You can do `const [errors, setErrors] = useState({ageError: false, userGenderError: false, ... });` and then use the callback like `setError({...errors, ageError: true})`;

Answer (score 1):

This looks like something you need to condense into a single useState. If you only expect one error at a time (even if they can be fairly close together) then you can simply have

```
[error, useError] = useState("");
```

And then set the error to "age" or "gender". In UseEffect, you use a switch to handle all possible use cases.

If you want multiple errors handled at a time, it looks pretty similar, but your useState starts out looking more like this

```
[error, useError] = useState({
age: true, gender: true, sexualOrientation: true, height: true
})
```

Again, with this method, you can use a single useEffect to monitor it.  To handle changing a single piece, you can use the spread operator

```
useError({...error, age: false})
```

which changes age to false, but keeps everything else the same.